# How to select a certain character from list which was created using a function

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, function, indexing

I would like to know if it is possible to index a list, if such list was made using a function.

For example, with the code given below, how would it be possible to print out the first (or second or third, etc.) character from the list I generate using the function?

This is my code:

```
import random
a="abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
def password(k):
  x=[]
  for n in range(k):
    x.append(random.choice(a))
  print(x)

password(6)
```

I would like to add a little more to this question, because I know how to print the characters one by one in the function but that is not exactly what I am looking for, what I wish to do is to compare two lists which were made by the function.

For example:

```
list1 = ['a','g','e','z','p','a']
list2 = ['l','g','t','h','a','f']
```

If we suppose that I generated these two lists of 6 characters using the function, is it possible to compare them in such way I can actually identify that the letter which coincides with the same index for both lists is `g` (the second letter)?

Comment: You can simply write print(x[0]) for first element and print(x[1]) for second element of the list below the print statement in your function.

Comment: you need to return x not print(x) so you can get password(6)[0]

Comment: ok, I understand what you mean, but I want to do something else with that. If I were to create TWO lists using the same function, and I would like to then compare the lists, looking if one of the letters coincide with the same index in both lists, how would I do that?. I had already tried the methods given, but if I create two 6 letter lists created by the function (in this case) what can I do in order to compare them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
list1 = ['a','g','e','z','p','a']
list2 = ['l','g','t','h','a','f']

common_positions = [i for i in range(len(list1)) if list1[i] == list2[i]]
common_chars = [list1[i] for i in common_positions]

print(common_positions)
print(common_chars)
```

Output:

> ```
> [1]
> ['g']
> ```

Now, if you want only the first coincided letter:

```
if common_chars:              # Test whereas this list is not empty
    print(common_chars[0])
```

Output:

> ```
> g
> ```

Comment: Thank you Marian. I appreciate the help.

Comment: @StivenG, you're welcome. Consider to upvote and/or accept my answer if it was useful for you.

Comment: my upvote is not publicly displayed since I have less than 15 of reputation, but I accepted your answer. Thanks again.